# Is possible cite an internet site (of an academical project) with the authors

Tags: publications, citations, paper-submission, bibtex

I am writing a paper about a project.

I must cite the internet site of the project with the results.

Question: can I cite, not only the site, but also the authors in the references?

**NOTE** The site is of research team where I work and is an institutional site (linked to my university).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attributing contributions to academic work that occur in Stack Exchange](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/attributing-contributions-to-academic-work-that-occur-in-stack-exchange)

Comment: I think that might depend on a particular publication style that you use (APA, Chicago, etc.). I would advise to consult the corresponding section of the style guide for specific guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should always provide all of the bibliographic information that you can.

In the citation of websites, authorship is often not given because authorship is either unstated, unclear, or complex.  If, however, the authorship of an online resource is clear, then you *must* list its authors, just as you would for any other source that you cite.

Comment: I'd add that a number of websites explicitly state how to cite them. It is thus better to firstly have a look for this kind of information.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: IMHO, the publication style guide should override the recommended citation by the website or its authors. Otherwise, the style of the publication will be inconsistent.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: the "how to cite" pages do not generally recommend a fixed citation style, but rather they can provide additional information (authors, title, release date, permanent link) not necessarily provided in the home page. This information can than be formatted in agreement with the publisher's preferred style.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: In my experience, many pages asked for a specific style, hence my comment. I'm glad that we agree on the main point, which is that publisher's preferred style should take precedence.

Comment: I would make it a WebCitation (http://www.webcitation.org/) so that your link continues to work even if the website you cited is later taken down.