# Citing StackExchange vs. Account Privacy?

Tags: publications, citations

In the answer to [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/107963/how-to-acknowledge-a-mathoverflow-user/108004#108004) and [similar questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/attributing-contributions-to-academic-work-that-occur-in-stack-exchange) it is recommended that you cite an idea or useful answer for your research work on StackExchange.

Now, if you have asked a question requiring a walk-back mathematical process (lets assume its a contribution) using fundamental knowledge to walk-back, if you do cite in this case, how do you keep the privacy of your account name? Since, people would check the answer and could look into the account history of the questioner and the answerer. Also, these StackExchange websites are linked and it seems that not everyone would like that for privacy reasons. So how could this be managed appropriately?

**Note**: This is a modification of an existing question marked as duplicate.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the privacy of your account regarding a mathematical question? I believe that most people should better give their real name in their StackExchange account. I see no benefit in using pseudos or "anonymous accounts" on a mathematical forum.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch maybe i don't want to be judged for dumb questions? or i want to keep private my other dumb questions in other stackexchange sites? well i guess there is always asking moderators to delete them. but eh. privacy.

Comment: If you want to keep your privacy, don't post questions you might want to use in your papers on StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

The post you reference has the solution to your doubt. Just cite when you encounter an original contribution or thank for helpful critics.

Answer (score -2):

Do you "have" to cite: Maybe, depends.
Should you ask the one you want to cite first: definitely.
Is there a way to protect your privacy: There are many, but I can't see a perfect one right now.

All in all, I think your question is hard to answer as it is, as it depends on too many things (field, kind of paper, kind of question/answer, persons involved,...).