# Coauthorship for answers on Stack Exchange

Tags: authorship

After spending some time on math.stackexchange, my impression is that a substantial part of the questions is asked by active professional researchers (PhD, postdoc, prof., etc). Let's suppose such a person is stuck in his/her research, asks a question on stackexchange, gets "unstuck" because of a good answer, and writes a paper about it. Shouldn't the person providing the helpful answer (however small the contribution in the overall paper) be offered co-authorship? More generally, is it ethical to crowd-source research on stackexchange without stating one's professional interest in the answer?

Comment: (Browsing recent questions on math.SE regularly, I think it is inaccurate to say professional researchers make up a substantial part of the question *askers* there. On MO, maybe.)

Comment: There's also a fairly large gap between "a helpful answer that smoothed things over" and "something that was sufficiently important to merit co-authorship". Hell, I have a friend who used a proposition I suggested in conversation once and I was happy enough when they credited me in the paper inline.

Comment: Also related (but closed): [Do I have to make someone coauthor if he/she solves a problem in StackExchange, asked by myself, which is later used in my paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/129895/17254)

Comment: *is it ethical to crowd-source research on stackexchange without stating one's professional interest in the answer?* Can someone translate this question into the plain English? I understand every word and the grammatical structure, but the meaning totally eludes me :-)