# Research article inspired by a question on MSE?

Tags: publications, etiquette

This question has been migrated from the [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130107/research-article-inspired-by-a-question-on-mse#comment8543248_4130107).

I am writing a short research article that was inspired by a question posted on the Mathematics Stack Exchange. Is mentioning this in the article viewed as unprofessional/undesirable?

I specifically mention in the introduction that the paper was motivated by an MSE question and provide a citation to the question but am not sure how an editor may view that. Is this a generally acceptable thing to do?

Comment: Related: [Attributing contributions to academic work that occur in Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1580/68109).

Comment: An example: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/14547/57642 . The paper in the answer cites the Stack Exchange question in its introduction, just as you describe.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Very helpful.  Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you weren't the original source of the question, then it is entirely proper that you mention and cite it.

Interesting mathematical questions can come from anywhere and from anyone. But if you are inspired by the thoughts of another person, then hey should get credit for that.

Ideally a citation should point to a real person, though anonymity on SO may make that impossible.

Comment: The OP has been fairly responsive to questions.  Are you suggesting to ask for their actual name to include in the citation?

Comment: It would be best if you could provide their real name and can ask, but, like myself, their anonymity might be more important to them. I don't think the mods have the power to put two people together.

Comment: If the OP is actually constructive, you might even consider collaborating on the topic.

Comment: +1 for @Ezze 's comment - work _with_ the OP if that is an option.